# Как сохранить картинки на комп при парсинге

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib

Мой код на питоне:

```
img = ['https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_231574.jpg',
               'https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_45515.jpg',
               'https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_240498.jpg'] 
for im in img:
    urlretrieve(im, 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pictures')
```

При этом выбрасывает ошибку:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pictures'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Конечно ты не можешь их поверх папки написать ;). Надо их в папку сохранять, вот пример кода:

```
img = ['https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_231574.jpg',
               'https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_45515.jpg',
               'https://dungs.rusmark.ru/components/com_jshopping/files/img_products/full_240498.jpg'] 
for im in img:
    urlretrieve(im, 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\pictures\\' + im.split('/')[-1])
```